# Why is the compiler unable to locate my file/class in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio

I am following the Microsoft music store tutorial for asp.net mvc 3 using visual studio 2010, sp1. http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-4 I am translating code into VB.

The tutorial says to add the following line to the application_start method of the Global.asax file, but the compiler says that it can't find the file sample data:

```
Sub Application_Start()
    System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(  //MvcMusicStore.Models.SampleData' is not defined.
           New MvcMusicStore.Models.SampleData())
           ...
End Sub
```

I'm confused why the compiler can't find this file because I have a SampleData.vb file under the models folder of the project, as shown in the picture below:

[image]

What am I missing?
 - I added a namespace statement around the SampleData class to ensure that it is in the same namespace as the overall project

```
Namespace MvcMusicStore
        Public Class SampleData
            Inherits DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges(Of MusicStoreEntities)
    ...
        End Class
    End Namespace
```

Comment: Is that the correct namespace?

Comment: Does the name of your actual class match the filename?

Comment: @KDiTraglia I added a namespace statement around the SampleData.vb class to ensure that it is in the same namespace as the overall project

Comment: @Brandon yes. see the addition above

Comment: Your `SampleData` is in `MvcMusicStore` namespace, but you referred it as `MvcMusicStore.Models.SampleData`. You should fix one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your namespace doesn't match your initialization.  Either change the namespace to read `Namespace MvcMusicStore.Models`, or change the initialization to say `new MvcMusicStore.SampleData()`

Actually since you are in the same namespace you should be able to just write

`new SampleData()`